# Posting an Event to Page Wall with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been knocking my head against a wall for two weeks now, poring over the net, poring over stackoverflow, and repeatedly testing and failing to get a script together to post an event to a Fan Page.  I've finally gotten a script that effectively creates the event, but it doesn't appear on the page.

After DMCS pointed me along to the PAGE access tokens, I fiddled about to generate them.  Now, the problem is that the event appears on my personal wall, not the page wall I'm targeting.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Here's the script after the latest edits:

```
    <?php
    $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $my_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/testfiles/fbeventform.php";

//Going to get the PAGE access code
//First to get USER Access Code
   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=create_event&scope=manage_pages";

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $access_token = @file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($access_token, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

    echo '<hr />' . $access_token;

//Now, getting the PAGE Access token, using the user access token

    $page_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" .  $page_id . "?fields=access_token&" . $access_token;
  $response = file_get_contents($page_token_url);

// Parse the return value and get the Page access token
  $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);

  $page_access_token = $resp_obj['access_token'];

    echo '<hr />' . $page_access_token;

//Post the event--here's the form function

if( !empty($_POST) && (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['start_time']) || empty($_POST['end_time'])) ) {
    $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
} elseif(!empty($_POST)) {
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $page_id . "/events?" . $access_token;
    $params = array();
    // Prepare Event fields
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        if(strlen($value))
            $params[$key] = $value;

    // Check if we have an image
    if( isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['picture']['name']) ) {
        $uploaddir = './upload/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $params['picture'] = "@" . realpath($uploadfile);
        }
    }  

    // Start the Graph API call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded['id'])) {
        // Event created successfully, now we can
        // a) save event id to DB AND/OR
        // b) show success message AND/OR
        // c) optionally, delete image from our server (if any)
        $msg = "Event created successfully: {$decoded['id']}";
    }
}
?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <p><label for="name">Event Name</label><input type="text" name="name" value="a" /></p>
        <p><label for="description">Event Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea></p>
        <p><label for="location">Location</label><input type="text" name="location" value="" /></p>
        <p><label for="">Start Time</label><input type="text" name="start_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" /></p>
        <p><label for="end_time">End Time</label><input type="text" name="end_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"))); ?>" /></p>
        <p><label for="picture">Event Picture</label><input type="file" name="picture" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="privacy_type">Privacy</label>
            <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="OPEN" checked='checked'/>Open&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="CLOSED" />Closed&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="SECRET" />Secret&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create Event" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This effectively creates the event, but it doesn't appear on the page wall I'm targetting.  I'm really at the end of my rope over this...

Any and all help is appreciated, and I will be happy to post final results for future users!

Comment: This question has been moved to another, follow-up, question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761569/posting-an-event-to-page-wall-with-php-the-proper-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug the access token you're using at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and ensure you have a PAGE access token and not a USER access token.

For getting a page access token, see "Page Login" part of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for those links!  It looks like I have an APP access token.  I changed my token call to reflect the information in the Authentication Docs, adding "manage_pages" to my request, which yielded the correct results--I was asked permission for the app to modify my pages.  However, I'm guessing there's something I'm leaving out of the submission process to keep it from appearing on the page itself.  Or, do I need to get a PAGE access token after all, not an APP token?

Comment: You need the PAGE access token. Do a GET to  `me/accounts` and you will see the PAGE access token there.

Comment: OK, I think I'll take the night off, and take another look in the morning.  I have my PAGE access tokens, but the script fails if I substitute those tokens for the APP access tokens, and I think i'm starting to see tokens everywhere I look ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  As you can see, this is my first stackoverflow post.  I'll definitely follow through, as your answer sent me in the right direction, I just needed a bit of coffee to see it!  Could you take a look at the problem as it stands now?  The event posts properly to my personal wall, but not the page intended with the page token I received.  I've got to missing the one last chunk...

Comment: Since your original issue was resolved, you may want to ask a new question as following Q via comments can be tricky.